# Script Kept on Running Though The Cell is Empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi everyone im having issues setting up this script where the script kepts on running though the cell the empty. Mind you that column B to Column D is formulated. Would really appreciate your help.

[image]

```
    function createNewGoogleDocs1() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1DschA_SiRHCb3Y259uB9YJTrgnOTLJ-Jwr1YjNGjJa8');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1zr9RBVENXvtO2WLLAmZm5VtAD5dUgGcQ')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('CP37 Interest')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

//Start processing each spreadsheet  row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[10]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    
    //Google Doc Replacement Text
    body.replaceText('{{REF2}}', row[0].toString());
    body.replaceText('{{REF4}}', row[1].toString());
    body.replaceText('{{REF1}}', row[2].toString());
    body.replaceText('{{REF3}}', row[3].toString());
    body.replaceText('{{VALUE1}}', row[4].toString());
    body.replaceText('{{VALUE2}}', row[5].toString());
    body.replaceText('{{VALUE3}}', row[6].toString());
    body.replaceText('{{TOTAL}}', row[7].toString());
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 10).setValue(url)
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  })
  
}
```

Here is the code, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

### You can add an additional `if` condition to skip the empty rows

Sample:

```
rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
  //if column A is empty - skip the current row
    if (row[0]== "") return;
    ...
  })
```

Note, that if `getDataRange()` returns you more rows than expected (including empty rows), most likely you have somewhere at the bottom of the sheet a non-empty cell. You can log `sheet.getDataRange().getA1Notation()` to find out where the unexpected last non-empty row is located.